# Scheduling Next Run date for weekly agent jobs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-agent, jobs

On SQL Server I used maintenance plan wizard to create three jobs:

| Job | Schedule |
| --- | --- |
| Job 1 | Every 3 week on Sunday |
| Job 2 | Every 3 week on Sunday |
| Job 3 | Every 3 week on Sunday |

I want the three jobs to run like so:

| Date | Job |
| --- | --- |
| Sun 2022-01-09 | Job 1 |
| Sun 2022-01-16 | Job 2 |
| Sun 2022-01-23 | Job 3 |
| Sun 2022-01-30 | Job 1 |
| Sun 2022-02-06 | Job 2 |
| Sun 2022-02-13 | Job 3 |

And so on. But Job Activity Monitor shows the "Next Run" date for all three jobs as `Sun 2022-01-09`. I tried to change the "Start date" of schedules to three consecutive Sundays in the past e.g. Sun 2021-12-19, Sun 2021-12-26 and Sun 2022-01-02 but no joy. Please advise.

Comment: Did you try using Frequency tab and define job1 to run every 3 weeks on Sunday starting from 9th January? Second job again with same recurrence starting from 16th Jan and job3 with same recurrence starting from 23rd January?

Comment: That works, thanks. Any idea why it cannot use past dates to determine the sequence?

Comment: You can use Past dates also by getting into "Duration" tab at start date column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be achieved using Frequency part of Scheduler.

You may create three jobs schedule, For Job1 as below:

[image]

Same thing will be repeated for Job2 and Job3 however you need to change start date to 16th and 23rd January in this part:

[image]

You may also use Past dated by changing date from the above calendar. After the job has executed, SQL Server will calculate a Next Execution date and time. So if you simply revert the system clock then it will be waiting for the next scheduled execution, it won't work that way. Better to schedule from current date and onwards.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Past dates do not seem to work. E.g. When I use 2021-12-19, 2021-12-26 and 2022-01-02 for Job 1, 2 and 3 they all have next date = Sun 2022-01-09.

Comment: After the job has executed, SQL Server will calculate a Next Execution date and time.  So if you simply revert the system clock then it will be waiting for the next scheduled execution, it won't work that way. Better to schedule from current date and onwards.